# If statement no longer recognizing input in while loop python

Tags: python

I am writing a hangman game in python and I have  variable called userguess and the user will type in what letter they want to use to guess. However, when the while loop begins it's second repeat, the if statement no longer recognizes the userguess and immediately concludes it to be an incorrect guess. I hope you don't mind the amount of code I am using as an example.

movieletters contains the hiddenword split into letters
defaultletters represents the blanks that have to be filled in by the user

I have tried using exception handlers by creating boolean variables but this hasn't done what I needed it to do.

```
userguess = input("Guess a letter: ")
        while True:
            for letter in movieletters:
                for defaultletter in defaultletters:
                    if userguess == letter:
                        print("You guessed correctly")
                        score += 1
                        guessedletters.append(userguess)
                        print(score, "/", totalletters)
                        print(guessedletters)
                        print(movie)
                        if score == totalletters:
                            print("\n")
                            print("*************************************************************************************************")
                            print(movie)
                            print("*************************************************************************************************")
                            print("\n")
                            print("You guessed all the letters correctly and uncovered the word!")
                            playagain = input("Would you like to play again? Type y for yes and n for no: ")
                            if playagain == "y":
                                main()
                            else:
                                quit()
                        userguess = input("Guess a letter: ")
                        continue

                    elif userguess != letter:
                        incorrectlyguessed += 1
                        print("INCORRECT!")
                        print(str(incorrectlyguessed) + "/" + str(tally))
                        if incorrectlyguessed == 1:
                            print("""






                                  __________""")
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 2:
                            print("""

                                  |
                                  |  
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 3:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |
                                  |  
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 4:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |         |
                                  |         
                                  |         
                                  |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 5:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |         |
                                  |         0
                                  |         
                                  |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 6:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |         |
                                  |         0
                                  |         |         
                                  |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 7:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |         |
                                  |         0
                                  |        \|/        
                                  |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 8:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |         |
                                  |         0
                                  |        \|/         
                                  |         |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 9:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |         |
                                  |         0
                                  |        \|/         
                                  |         |
                                  |________/_\              """)

                        if incorrectlyguessed == tally:
                            print("GAME OVER!")
                            print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                            print(movie)
                            print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                            playagain = input("Would you like to play again? Type y for yes and n for no: ")
                            if playagain == "y":
                                main()
                            else:
                                quit()
                        userguess = input("Guess a letter: ")
                        continue
```

I expect the output to show that the character is recognized as one of the letters in the hidden word in the while loop's second phase. This also effects all of the while loop's phases except for the first one.

Here's an example of the current output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlk14.png)

if the movie was cars then movieletters would be ['c', 'a', 'r', 's']
defaultletters would be _ _ _ _

Comment: Can you post what ```movieletters``` and ```defaultletters``` might contain?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi I have just updated the post.

Comment: Could you give an example version of your game and the error

Comment: Please show *exact* contents of `movieletters` and `defaultletters` enough to be able to reproduce your error.  A description does not really help.

Comment: Harvey, I am glad that you started learning python! I think you should take step back and think over what does your code really do. For example there is (probably) unnecessary loop and it seems that you don't need `defaultletter` variable.

Comment: @cdarke i've updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that it always matches with the first letter in the list of movieletters.

use if userguess in movieletters to check whether it matches or not

```py
userguess = input("Guess a letter: ")
        if userguess in movieletters:
            print("You guessed correctly")
            score += 1
            guessedletters.append(userguess)
            print(score, "/", totalletters)
            print(guessedletters)
            print(movie)
            if score == totalletters:
                print("\n")
                print("*************************************************************************************************")
                print(movie)
                print("*************************************************************************************************")
                print("\n")
                print("You guessed all the letters correctly and uncovered the word!")
                playagain = input("Would you like to play again? Type y for yes and n for no: ")
                if playagain == "y":
                    main()
                else:
                    quit()
            userguess = input("Guess a letter: ")
            continue

        else :
            incorrectlyguessed += 1
            print("INCORRECT!")
            print(str(incorrectlyguessed) + "/" + str(tally))
            if incorrectlyguessed == 1:
                print("""






                      __________""")
            elif incorrectlyguessed == 2:
                print("""

                      |
                      |  
                      |
                      |
                      |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 3:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |
                                  |  
                                  |
                                  |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 4:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |         |
                                  |         
                                  |         
                                  |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 5:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |         |
                                  |         0
                                  |         
                                  |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 6:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |         |
                                  |         0
                                  |         |         
                                  |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 7:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |         |
                                  |         0
                                  |        \|/        
                                  |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 8:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |         |
                                  |         0
                                  |        \|/         
                                  |         |
                                  |__________              """)
                        elif incorrectlyguessed == 9:
                            print("""
                                  -----------
                                  |         |
                                  |         0
                                  |        \|/         
                                  |         |
                                  |________/_\              """)

                        if incorrectlyguessed == tally:
                            print("GAME OVER!")
                            print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                            print(movie)
                            print("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                            playagain = input("Would you like to play again? Type y for yes and n for no: ")
                            if playagain == "y":
                                main()
                            else:
                                quit()
                        userguess = input("Guess a letter: ")
                        continue
```

Comment: Thanks! Brilliant!